# Tigerpaw API For Support or Creating support ticket

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, integrate

Anyone have any Idea about Tigerpaw API For Support or Creating support ticket. my requirement is integrate this API in codeigniter website. But I have no Any idea Please suggest me how can i Complete my task.  http://www.tigerpawsoftware.com/

Comment: Is there documentation of software API you want to use? Try to follow it. Before that you would need to mastery [CodeIgniter REST](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) since it is more than likely third party APIs use it. If you didn't work with CI REST start [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814).